# Javascript execution order via HTML5 script tag with async attribute

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

Aloha. I have been working on a script and though I understand documentation of each constituent of the problem (and have looked over many other questions on SO), I don't understand this specific behavior in practice. Please be aware that the following code is an abbreviated subset that isolates the specific issue. Here is `async.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="asyncTest.js" async="true"></script></head>
<body><ul id="menu"><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul></body></html>
```

And here is `asyncTest.js`:

```
var _site = function() {
  var load = function() {
    var menuCategory = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0; i<menuCategory.length; i++) { alert(i+'['+menuCategory[i]+']'); }
  };

  return { load:load };
}();
window.addEventListener('load',_site.load(),false);
```

The problem is that without the `async` attribute in the `<script>` tag, this code does not properly store the `<li>` elements into `menuCategory`, as though it were running prior to the DOM being loaded (even though I thought it should fire after the entire `window` "object" loads). I find that strange because I am using the `addEventListener()` to try and run this only after the whole thing has been loaded (and it appears to run at the appropriate time in Chromium, FF, and Opera -- at least what appears to be the "appropriate time"). If anything, I think that the opposite would cause this behavior.

Can someone explain this, preferably using the old Einstein "explain it like you're explaining it to a six-year-old"? I'm obviously missing something in my reading. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `_site.load()` will call `_site.load` immediately and pass the result to `window.onload`. Is that what you want? It's more common to pass a function reference to be called later: `window.addEventListener('load',_site.load,false);` (note missing parenthesis).

Comment: That's obviously not what is wanted. I was about to write this as answer...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Can you please write this up so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by RobG in the comments, the problem here is that using `_site.load()` (with parenthesis after the call) is causing the function to be executed AND THEN assigned to the `onload` event. The way to correct this behavior to the desired functionality is to call it without the parenthesis: `_site.load` (or `_site().load`).